# Remove profile links from twitter widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, twitter

I need to remove twitter profile links from a twitter widget **iframe** on a primary school website (some of those parents swear a lot! The head doesn't want kids to click on a link on a school website to someone with limited vocabulary!)

Here's my code - which works in FF but not Chrome or IE!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("iframe").load(function() {
jQuery("iframe#twitter-widget-0").contents().find("a.profile").each(function(index) {
    jQuery(this).removeAttr('href');
    });
});
</script>
```

How can I make it work cross browser, bearing in mind the twitter widget is sent by twitter as an iframe so loads late!

Comment: You could use the API to generate the content yourself, therefore having full control over markup and content

Comment: i dont think so! since the new API is out, you cant do that anymore!

Comment: That's right, can't use api, so how can I use jquery to kill links with class="profile" in the iframe please?

Comment: Well one can't manipulate an iframe with external content for security reasons